# RxJS switchMap returns T instead of Observable<number>

Tags: typescript, rxjs6

I can't seem to get the RxJS switchMap to return the correct type.
Typescript says `Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'number'.`
How can I change the type so that it will be correct?

My stop/start counter works just fine when I type it to 'any', but I want to do it right :)

Here's a link to a [live example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-3b7yyf) on stackblitz.

But the actual issue is within the `tap((count: number)`

```
private counter$: Observable<number> = this.isCounting$.pipe(
    switchMap(isCounting => isCounting ? this.updateCount() : of(this.count)),
    tap((count: number) =>  {
      this.displayCount(count)
    })
)
```

Would love Typescript to say the type is , but when hovering `tap((count: number)` it says:

[ts] Argument of type 'MonoTypeOperatorFunction' is not assignable to parameter of type 'OperatorFunction'.

Types of parameters 'source' and 'source' are incompatible.
    Type 'Observable' is not assignable to type 'Observable'.
      Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'number'. [2345]

Update:
There's no error in TS 2.9.2 
There IS an error in TS 3.2.2

Comment: Where is the error? I don't see it on your stackblitz

Comment: I found out that the error is only there in TS 3.2.2

Comment: Hmmm... For some reason Stackblitz doesn't show the error. I have the same versions in my package.json and I can see that TSLint 3.3.1 is running.